# Adding categories to product prestashop

Tags: php, sql, prestashop, webshop

So I've been dealing with this problem for quite some time and can't find a clear solution. So basically I'm adding new products directly into db using **Product** object. For now it went well but I can't manage to link new products with a category.

```
$cat_ids = [];
    foreach ($value['kat_naziv'] as $cat_val) {
    $cat_ids[] = (int)$luceed->selectCategoryIds($cat_val)[$cat_val]['id_category'];
}

$product->id_category = 3;
$product->id_category_default = 3;

$product->save();

$product->addToCategories($cat_ids);
```

So basically $cat_ids is an array of integers that i'm getting from db where name is something i pass as a parameter to selectCategoryIds;

What is the problem here why it wont associate newly created product with categories i give to it

Comment: You can test your $cat_ids array by this code print_r($cat_ids); die(); I have a feeling that you don't have any element in this array. Also Product object doesn't have id_category.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 12
)

This is what it outputs. I doubt the problem lies there since i've tried with this line of code and nothing happens 
$product->addToCategories(array(3,4,5));

Comment: i've tried that before and i've found the answer somewhere that addToCategories is working only with created products therefore save() should be run before addToCategories

Comment: I just removed my comment about that after i try myself to test your code. I've just tested  $product->addToCategories(array(3,4,5)); on my demo prestashop. working great!

Comment: absolutely no idea why this happens to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FMEModule That's exactly what i did there but i've filled the array with the id's of categories from the database

Anyways I ended up writing my own queries for associatting products with categories

Answer (score 2):

After creating your new product ( i.e $product = new Product() ). You can assign categories to product using.

```
$product->updateCategories($category_array);
```

where

```
$category_array = array("0" => "2", "1" => "3", "4" => "6"...... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Version (1.6)

I found the following bug in `Product.php`, in `addToCategories`, search for `if (!in_array($new_id_categ, $current_categories))` (line 964),

notice that the `if` is missing `{}` - add them, and the problem is solved:

```
    foreach ($categories as $new_id_categ) {

        if (!in_array($new_id_categ, $current_categories)) {

            if ($position == null) {
                $position = (int)$new_categ_pos[$new_id_categ];
            }
            $product_cats[] = array(
                'id_category' => (int)$new_id_categ,
                'id_product' => (int)$this->id,
                'position' => $position,
            );
        }

    }
```

Prestashop developer LOVEs omitting `{}` after `if` and `foreach` - this is supper annoying and bug prone.

This issue is fixed in the repo:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Product.php

NOTE: this solution solves the bug in the following scenario - `a product that is already link to a category is link to another category (while keeping the original category)`
although I'm not sure if this is the scenario in the question.